# An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, app.xaml

am trying to navigate from 1 page to other in windows phone8 mobile app.
its giving error-
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

XAML:

```
<phone:PivotItem Header="item1">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <HyperlinkButton Content="Transfer" Click="hyperlinkButton1_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</phone:PivotItem>
```

C# Code:

```
private void hyperlinkButton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AboutUs.xaml", UriKind.Relative));               

    //NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AboutUs.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AboutUs.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    });
}
```

Comment: You will not need the dispatcher as you are already running on the UI thread.. But are you sure about the page name and its location? When you debug, the exception gets thrown after calling Navigate on the Navigation Service?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need two steps:

1. Remove the block of Dispatcher, you are on UI thread in Click method.just:

   **NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("your uri", UriKind.Relative));**
2. Check the uri string you want to navigate, such as `Spell`, `Up or Low Case` and so on.

Comment: NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/AboutUs.xaml", UriKind.Relative));  now its working for me